# ASP MVC Button Click

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to click on  button and use Next method in Controller, but i dont want go to another view! I want stay here in VIEW and my property should be change. This idea doesnt work :(( How can i do it??
Its my controller

```
 public class VisitsController : Controller
{

    Terminarz terminarz = new Terminarz();
    Daty data = new Daty();

    public VisitsController()
    {
        terminarz.aktualnaData = DateTime.Now.Date;
        terminarz.pierwszyDzienTyg = data.pierwszyDzienTygodnia(terminarz.aktualnaData);
        terminarz.ostatniDzienTyg = data.ostatniDzienTygodnia(terminarz.aktualnaData);
    }
    [ActionName("index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.data = terminarz.aktualnaData;
        ViewBag.pierwszyDzien = terminarz.pierwszyDzienTyg.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy ");
        ViewBag.ostatniDzien = terminarz.ostatniDzienTyg.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy ");
        ViewBag.wtf = terminarz.pierwszyDzienTyg.AddDays(7).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy ");

        return View();
    }

    [NonAction]
    public ActionResult Next()
    {
        terminarz.pierwszyDzienTyg = terminarz.pierwszyDzienTyg.AddDays(7);
        terminarz.ostatniDzienTyg = terminarz.ostatniDzienTyg.AddDays(-7);
        return View("index");
    }
```

}

my model

```
public partial class Terminarz
{

    public DateTime aktualnaData { get; set; }
    public DateTime pierwszyDzienTyg { get; set; }
    public DateTime ostatniDzienTyg { get; set; }
    public string nazwa { get; set; }


}
```

my view

```
@ViewBag.pierwszyDzien<br />
@ViewBag.ostatniDzien<br />
@ViewBag.wtf
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("dalej","Next", "Visits")
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: What isn't working?  Specifying a string in `View()` is exactly how you specify a particular view.  What does `NonAction` do?  Why are you using the same view?  Has nothing changed during the page request?  If you want to stay on the same page, why not send data to the server via AJAX instead of a form post?

Comment: @David is right, use AJAX.

Comment: my idea doesnt work :/ i would like click on my button(actionlink) in my View and change property pierwszyDzienTyg but stay in the same page!! and i should see result :) What Should I read, study? thx for anser

Answer (score 2):

By default, all public methods in a controller can be called from an HTTP request. NonAction prevents the public method from being called from your form post. Remove the NonAction attribute from the Next method, and it should execute as expected.

You may also have to update your return to match a relative path something like this:

```
    return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml");
```

Your form is also not being submitted. You are using a link inside of the form. Try this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Next", "VisitsController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <button type="submit">Next</button>
    }
```

Comment: still not working, error "'System.NullReferenceException." my Model is null, when i want to display.. error its here 
  <tr>
     @foreach(var item in Model)
    {                          <td>@item.pierwszyDzienTyg.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy ")</td>
      }  </tr>